# Gesture Listener on Action Bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, gesture, gesture-recognition

Is it possible to implement Gesture Listener on a single item on Action Bar?I want to implement Gesture listener on search item i.e. on sliding search button a different activity opens up and on tapping it only once, it shows default search option.
Do I need to create a custom Action Bar or it can be done with default Action Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone need assistance in similar situation. This is the solution:-
Create a custom action bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:focusable="true" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_query"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_communities"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Create Gesture listener class:-

```
  public class Swipe_listener implements OnTouchListener {


protected final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}


public Swipe_listener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}


private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    //  Log.d("HELLOHELLOHELLOGELLO", "Here I am");
        float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (distanceX > 0)
                onSwipeRight();
            else
                onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

And in Main Activity:-

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);


    actionBar.setCustomView(v);

    v.setOnTouchListener(new Swipe_listener(getApplicationContext()){

        public void onSwipeRight() {
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent miN=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Prefer_circular.class);
            startActivity(miN);
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
         //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    });
```

Code taken from multiple questions from stackoverflow.com